# React: mapStateToProps - How do I get state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps to pass function and state to myComponent, I can get function but can't get state. My code looks like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state.editor
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onLoad: (payload) => dispatch(actionCreators.myFunc(payload)),}
});

function myComponent({errors, match, onLoad}) {
  //function myComponent({errors, match, onLoad, state}) { //state undefined
  //function myComponent({errors, match, onLoad}, state) { //state undefined
  // How do I get state here?
  console.log(state) //always undefined
  console.log(state.editor) //undefined
   console.log(editor) //undefined
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

Comment: Did you want `(state) => ({ editor: state.editor })`? Right now you're unpacking whatever's *in* `state.editor` to *separate* props. Also note the name of that prop would be `editor`, not `state` - remove the destructuring in the function parameter list, `console.log(props)` and see what you're receiving.

Comment: it just simplefied example. I can't remove destruction :(, cos it will brake all other code. so I need somehow do it with destruction if it possible.

Comment: You don't have to entirely remove the destructuring, just move it inside the function instead so you can look at what props you receive. Otherwise debugging is much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `mapStateToProps` like below

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  editor:state.editor
});
```

Typically example for `Functional component` is

```js
function YourComponent({ yourProp }) {
  return <p>{yourProp}</p>
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { yourProp: state.yourProp };
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```